# Are there any as or bs that violate this condition

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$$0<\left|x-\frac{c_n}{d_n}\right|>\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}d_k}$$

Let  $$x=\frac{1}{\frac{b}{a}-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{b^k}$$
which is equal to
$$\frac{1}{\frac{b}{a}-1}=\frac{1}{\frac{b-a}{a}}=\frac{a}{b-a}$$ .

Suppose $a$ and $b$ are members of the natural numbers with $b$ greater than $a$ and both are never equal to each other.

Then let:
$$c_n=d^n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a^k}{b^k}$$
$$d_n=\frac{b}{a}$$
$$0<\left|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{b^k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a^k}{b^k}\right|>\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{b}{a}}$$
Which is equal to

$$0<\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{b^k}\right|>\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}a}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}b}$$
$$0<\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{b^k}\right|>\frac{a^n}{b^n}$$

Are there any natural numbers $a$s and $b$s that violate this condition?

Answer (score 1):

Note the summation in your final line is of an infinite [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), so this gives

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{a^k}{b^k} = \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{k} = \frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n+1}}{1 - \frac{a}{b}} = \frac{\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n}}{\frac{b}{a} - 1} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, when comparing to

$$\frac{a^n}{b^n} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

you have \eqref{eq1A} is greater than \eqref{eq2A} if $\frac{b}{a} - 1 \lt 1 \implies b \lt 2a$, is equal to it if $\frac{b}{a} - 1 = 1 \implies b = 2a$, and is less than it if $\frac{b}{a} - 1 \gt 1 \implies b \gt 2a$.